# How would I ask java to stop until a variable is changed?

Tags: java, swing, variables, bluej

so I am trying to design a GUI with the program BlueJ, that sends data from a jtextfield box into a variable (already done), and using that variable to be able to update another variable, but for java to "stop running" until a specific variable is updated. So something along the lines of...

```
string bacon = "";
int agility = 1;
int dexterity = 2;
int strength = 3;
int intelligence = 4;
int charisma = 5;
//my variables.

if (bacon = "agility")
{
//what I am doing goes below where words are being used instead
Stop java progression until bacon is updated with an integer.
agility= agility+bacon
}
else if (bacon = "dexterity")
{
//what I am doing goes below where words are being used instead
Stop java progression until bacon is updated with an integer.
dexterity = dexterity+bacon
}
else if (bacon = "strength")
{
//what I am doing goes below where words are being used instead
Stop java progression until bacon is updated with an integer.
strength = strength+bacon
}
else if (bacon = "intelligence")
{
//what I am doing goes below where words are being used instead
Stop java progression until bacon is updated with an integer.
intelligence = intelligence+bacon
}
else if (bacon = "charisma")
{
//what I am doing goes below where words are being used instead
Stop java progression until bacon is updated with an integer.
charisma = charisma+bacon
}
```

Thank you very much to anybody who can help me figure this out. I would also like it to have something so that if bacon is stated as a non-integer (32.7 or "hello"), it would simply ask you to input a proper integer.

Comment: Note that you use `==` to compare, not `=`, but having said that, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: This confuses me. Bacon is a string that you expect to be an integer that you expect to be one of a few strings that are character attributes? Hrnh?

Comment: As for your problem, look into using an observer design pattern, so that you're notified if a variable has changed. One waty to do this is to make the variable a "bound property" by using PropertyChangeSupport and a PropertyChangeListener. Please check [this site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) for a decent tutorial on this subject. Note that Swing components already have PropertyChangeSupport.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Thank you for correcting me on my usage of = signs, I replaced the majority of them with the use of equalsIgnoreCase() since capitalization shouldn't matter in the context I'm making.
And thank you for the bound property link, they look like they will work for my project, although, i seem to be getting back an error code of "illegal start of expression" when I use it. If you would like, I could make a pastebin of my code, and point you to where this error is being stated. And sorry about any blaring errors in my code, I started learning java... four days ago or so.

Comment: @MichaelMerrick instead of a pastebin consider creating a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: See [*Validating Input*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking in the first part of the question, but for the second part to it check if it is a non integer you can do something like this....

```
boolean isValidInput = true;
for(int i=0;i<bacon.length();i++) {
    char charAt = bacon.charAt(i);
    if(!Character.isDigit(charAt)) {
        isValidInput = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(!isValidInput)
    System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
```

Also, `=` is used for assignment in java, ex `a = 3;`, however if you are trying to check if something is equal to something else, you should use the `==` operator. ex. `if(x==2)`
But in your case, since you are comparing Strings, you should use `if(x.equals("hello"))`

Another tip, instead of saying `charisma = charisma + bacon;` you can just say `charisma += bacon;` as a shorthand ;)

Hope this helps,
Saashin